# Python: change column of strings with None to 0/1

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"label":['a', 'b', None, 'c', None]})
```

and I wish to change it such that all `None` are set to `0` and everything else is set to `1`.
I used `df.iterrows()` but it really feels barbaric and seems to be slow.

What would be an efficient, pythonic way?

Comment: `df['label'].isna().astype(int)`

Comment: `df.label.notna().mul(1)`

Comment: first comment does exact the opposite but the second one looks great

Comment: @QuangHoang I think that is backward. Maybe `notnull()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the following

```
df.label.notna().mul(1)
```

```
df.label.map({None: 0}).fillna(1).astype(int)
```

```
import numpy as np
np.where(df.label.isna(), 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if_else` from [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datar.all import f, mutate, if_else, is_na
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"label":['a', 'b', None, 'c', None]})
>>> df >> mutate(if_else(is_na(f.label), 0, 1))
     label         x
  <object> <float64>
0        a       1.0
1        b       1.0
2     None       0.0
3        c       1.0
4     None       0.0
>>> # or
>>> if_else(is_na(df.label), 0, 1)
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
4    0.0
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"label":['a', 'b', None, 'c', None]})
print(df)
print('-------------------')
df = df.fillna(value=0)
print(df)
```

You can read more about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)